# Clear / erase a mistyped invisible password on a shell / terminal in Linux

Tags: terminal, input

One thing that annoys me using Linux's terminal is when I have to type a invisble password, like when you run **ssh**. Sometimes I mistype one or more letters and then I have to press backspace key a few times to make sure that I erased everything to start again.

I know this is not a big deal but since on the other day I found out that pressing CTRL+L "clears" the terminal I was wondering if there's a way to clear/erase the invisible password without relying on backspace or pressing enter key to try again.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You just have to type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>.

Enjoy =)

Comment: Never knew about that. Usually I'd just ctrl+C out of an unwanted command mid-typing.

Comment: See my explanation in the other answer if you want to know what's going on.

Comment: I'm using Ctrl+W and pretty OK with it.

Answer (score 120):

I know this was already answered, but the answer doesn't explain what's going on.

Characters like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> are handled by the **application**.  In the case of entering input into the shell, like `bash`, it clears the screen.  Some applications, like `emacs`, use it to redraw the screen and/or recenter the cursor.

Characters like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> at a password prompt are handled by the [**TTY line discipline**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline).  They'll work any time the input terminal is in the "canonical" line-editing mode, which is what mode your programs are in while you're entering a password.  In this mode, it's the Linux kernel itself that is interpreting these characters.  You can see what functions are assigned to which keys in the output of `stty -a`:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 45; columns 128; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S;
susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

Here, you can see that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> is tied to `kill`, which (according to the [stty man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stty)) will "erase the current line".  You could also use `stty` to change this mapping:

```
stty kill ^E   # make ctrl-e erase the line
```

[This page](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php) has a lot of great information about the TTY layer if you're interested.

---

If things weren't confusing enough: when at the prompt of an interactive `bash`, you're actually **not** in the "canonical" line-editing mode.  Instead, `bash` is receiving each character directly as you type it, and interpreting the control sequences itself, through the [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library.  This library *will* honor the mappings you've set on your terminal device, though, so you can still use `stty` to change them.  Or, you can customize them independently inside `bash` and other readline-based programs by setting the `unix-line-discard` property inside your `~/.inputrc` file.  See the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for more info.

When you run a program, `bash` re-enables canonical line editing mode (`stty icanon`) if it was enabled before, and then disables it again when the program finishes (`stty -icanon`).

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to trace down and fix my tilda / yay 'erase' issue!