# Bind Ctrl-\ in inputrc?

Tags: bash, terminal, inputrc

I've been futzing around with this and can't seem to get it to work. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in the terminal correctly outputs `^\` for this combination so it should be recognizable.

As I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> bound to suspend-frame in emacs, I would like to be able to quickly get back into the foreground with another press of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

I believe this is the only viable combination:

```
"\C-\\": "fg\n"
```

If I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for this combination, I get the following output, which might be useful:

```
bash: $'\034': command not found
```

Comment: What happens if you type `stty quit undef`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ctrl+\ is one of the control characters that cause the terminal to send a signal (SIGQUIT), like Ctrl+C (SIGINT) and Ctrl+Z (SIGTSTP). You can run `stty -a` to show what characters have a special meaning to the terminal; see [Clear / erase a mistyped invisible password on a shell / terminal in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50493/clear-erase-a-mistyped-invisible-password-on-a-shell-terminal-in-linux/50516#50516) for more details. The upshot is that when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, bash doesn't see a character on its standard input, it sees a signal, and that doesn't go through the key bindings mechanisms.

You can switch off the meaning for the character in the terminal with the command `stty quit undef`. If you do that, bash will see the character as input and your key binding will take effect.

To arrange for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> to be a bash binding but have its normal terminal binding when running a command, change the terminal settings [before](https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command) and after running a command.

```
preexec () {
  stty quit '^\'
}
precmd () {
  stty quit undef
}

preexec_invoke_exec () {
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return  # do nothing if completing
    [ "$BASH_COMMAND" = "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] && return # don't cause a preexec for $PROMPT_COMMAND
    local this_command=`HISTTIMEFORMAT= history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//"`;
    preexec "$this_command"
}
trap 'preexec_invoke_exec' DEBUG
PROMPT_COMMAND='precmd'
```

Rather than make the key type `fg` and a newline, bind the key to a shell command. You can't do that from `.inputrc`, which applies to all readline applications, not just to bash. Instead, define a bash binding in your `.bashrc`:

```
bind -x '"\C-\\": "fg"'
```

Comment: Adding `stty quit undef` and `bind -x '"\C-\\": "fg"'` to my .bashrc worked great and does not interfere with emacs. I'm not aware of Ctrl+\ behaving like Ctrl-c in any application; at least in my terminal emulator (mintty). Where might I have a problem with this?

Comment: @Zhro Ctrl+\\ sends SIGQUIT. That is the case on your terminal, otherwise you wouldn't have needed to ask this question. That does cause many applications to quit, but not all — bash ignores it, for example.

Comment: I will keep your workaround on-hand just in case. Thanks so much.

Comment: You can set macros in `~/.inputrc` only for bash by wrapping them in an if construct like this :
`$if Bash
$endif`

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get this particular script to work for me, but I managed to get a [variation](https://gist.github.com/sebastiancarlos/762ac6da14a3180f7ce2409889a6de81) to work using the external library "bash-preexec", which essentially does the same thing.